# Conflict between R and Openfoam in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I'm working on a pc with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and  this computer has OpenFoam libraries. Recently, I installed the R software. I didn't have any problem during the installing process of R. The problem that I found was related to running R. When I write R in the terminal, I get this:

```
luke@glinux:~$ R
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
| =========                 |                                                 |
| \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox           |
|  \\    /   O peration     | Version:  2.2.0                                 
|   \\  /    A nd           | Web:      www.OpenFOAM.org                      |
|    \\/     M anipulation  |                                                 |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Build  : 2.2.0-5be49240882f
Exec   : R
Date   : Mar 15 2014
Time   : 10:56:27
Host   : "glinux"
PID    : 7525
Case   : /home/luke
nProcs : 1
sigFpe : Enabling floating point exception trapping (FOAM_SIGFPE).
fileModificationChecking : Monitoring run-time modified files using timeStampMaster
allowSystemOperations : Disallowing user-supplied system call operations
// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
Create time
fileName::stripInvalid() called for invalid fileName UbuntuOne
    For debug level (= 2) > 1 this is considered fatal
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why, when I want to work with R, does the terminal show me the OpenFoam version? 
What could I do to solve this problem?

Comment: what does `which -a R` tell you?  At first glance it looks as though OpenFoam puts an executable file called `R` into your search path ...

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, thanks for your reply to my question. The command _which_ got me two lines, one of them is     /opt/openfoam220/platforms/linuxGccDPOpt/bin/R     and the other line is:     /usr/bin/R    . I guess the system is setting that two programs have a same variable for runs different processes. For this reason... the conflict between R and OpenFoam. I was thinking to modify my bashrc file in order to turn off OpenFoam when I will use R. But I don't know if this solution is practical, because when I would like to use OpenFoam I will modify again my bashrc file. What do you think?

Comment: why not just run `/usr/bin/R` ? or set up an alias for R?

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, I got it. You are right with an alias for R, I would solve this problem. Thank you for your support!

Comment: OpenFoam requires a line at the end of .bashrc to source the openfoam binaries: `. /opt/openfoam230/etc/bashrc`. Can I alter this instead to be an export of $PATH? Or will that then affect more than just the bash shell?

Comment: In my case the conflict is made apparent with `whereis` rather than `which`. It is indeed the case that OpenFoam has stolen the name from R, or rather taken permission to do so from the invocation in `.bashrc` for sourcing (`.`) aliases from `/opt/openfoam<version>/etc/bshrc`. Ben's suggestion is valid: try launching R after `alias R='/urs/bin/R' and `unalias R` respectively

Comment: @BenBolker I'd suggest that Ben converts his comment into an answer and that Luke accepts it

Answer (score 3):

You can figure out what versions of R the system knows about (and which it is going to use by default) by running `which -a R` or `whereis R`.

If you want to run the statistical program R instead of the OpenFoam thing, you could run `/usr/bin/R` (fill in the real full path for your system),  or set up an alias for R: `alias R=/usr/bin/R` (thanks to @XavierStuvw)